# play flash in browser with menu

Tags: html, flash

I only got a swf file and now it should be embeded in a Html file.
I try it like

```
<object data="movie.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="myflash" width="320" height="240">
<param name="movie" value="movie.swf" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<param name="height" value="100" />
<param name="width" value="200" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="menu" value="false" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="samedomain" />
</object>
```

But I never done that before... so I try many things I read... but how can I get the player to show play, pause and such buttons?
After that I try Html5 video tag (mp4,ogg and webm) but it only works in chrome and firefox and never in IE 9/10.

Comment: oyu will need to look at adding them buttons usually i would pack them as a skin as such

Comment: An swf flash file does not always mean it is a video with play, stop, pause, etc buttons. It can be a game, a form, an advertisement, a sound, an image, etc. It depends on what is inside the flash swf file. So, for you the buttons you mentioned would need to be set inside the flash file in whatever way you (or whoever created the swf) would want it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!--[if IE]>
    <object
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        data="movie.swf"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0"
        width="200"
        height="400">
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <param name="movie" value="movie.swf" />
    </object>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <object
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        data="movie.swf"
        width="200"
        height="400">
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <param name="movie" value="movie.swf" />
    </object>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

And replace "movie.swf" by the realname of your flash file